# How do I download a bunch of files from a remote server, and concatenate them in a certain order using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, javascript

I'm trying to read the contents of a bunch of javascript files on a server, and then concatenate them into a new local file. The files have to be concatenated in a specific order (specified in an array). Here's what I have so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var commonWebFiles = getCommonWebDependenciesInOrder();
var fileContents = [];
var path = '/folder/';

fs.mkdir("target");
for(var i = 0, l = commonWebFiles.length; i < l; ++i){
    getFileContents(path, commonWebFiles[i]);
}

function getCommonWebDependenciesInOrder(){
    //Hit manager to get an correctly ordered array of common web dependencies
    //Stub
    return [
        'file1.js',
        'file2.js',
        'file3.js'
    ];
 };

function getFileContents(path, filename){
    var contents = "";
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("target/" + filename, {'flags': 'a'});
    var options = {
        host: 'ahost.net',
        port: 80,
        path: path + filename
    };
    var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
         res.on('data', function(chunk) {
             contents += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        writeStream.write(contents, encoding='binary');
        writeStream.end();
        fileContents[filename] = contents;

     });

     }).on('error', function(e) {
         console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
     });
};
```

This downloads the files and recreates them locally, but it seems a little clunky. When I tried to just write a single file directly from a looped set of requests, I got the chunks out of order....I feel like there must be an easier way....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    request = require('request');

// Utility function to overcome request's callback (err, response, body) where we're only interested in err and body
function simpleRequest(url, callback) {
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        callback(err, body);
    });
}

async.map(urls, simpleRequest, function(err, results) {
    if(err)
        return console.error(err);
    fs.writeFile(outfile, results.join(''));
});
```