# How can i download video by enter url in codeiginiter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, force-download

Paste Youtube url and submit worked with database perfect. But i wish to download that url video at the same time of submit. 
How can i download?..

in View file

```
<form name="videoUpload" id="videoUpload" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="url" id="url" >
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Ajax

```
var expData = "url="+url;
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('video/upload'); ?>",
      data: expData, 
      //dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
           alert(data);
            //$("#cmsuc").html(data);
        },
       error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Videos are also files. If you know the url this works. only downloading the file.

[How do I download a bunch of files from a remote server, and concatenate them in a certain order using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620435/how-do-i-download-a-bunch-of-files-from-a-remote-server-and-concatenate-them-in)

Comment: sorry, Cant to understand

Comment: you just need to implement a file download.